# a (recursive) function that will calculate sum for a given n

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

How to write a recursive function that will calculate this sum for a given n?

```
 n
 ∑  1/k
k=1
```

My code:

```
def sum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return sum(1/n) + sum(1/n+1)

print(sum(3))
```

For `n = 3` the output should be: `1.8333333333333333`

Comment: Can you please edit your sum notation, it's not clear what series you are trying to produce.

Comment: can you mention your equation precisely ??

Comment: Given that the output for n = 3 should be 11/6, I am guessing you want sum_{k = 1 to n} 1/k ; *i.e.*, 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n ?

Comment: You should reconsider calling your function `sum`, since that is the name of a built-in function.

Comment: In which case please note that python is not really a good language for recursion; there is already [a function called `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) in python; and you can achieve what you want by using this builtin function as well as a list comprehension, as simply as `return sum(1/k for k in range(n+1))`

Comment: @Stef This is likely homework, not a "real world" problem.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That's also my guess. It makes my comments all the more relevant.

Comment: Nobody would write this function recursively, so what does *(recursive)* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid declaring a new function with the name `sum` as there already exists a built-in function with this name.

You can recursively calculate

```
 n                              n-1
 ∑  1/k         ==         1/n + ∑  1/k
k=1         for n > 0           k=1
```

with

```
def my_recursive_sum(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return 1/n + my_recursive_sum(n-1)

print(my_recursive_sum(3))
```

Comment: Why would `sum(0)` return 0 ? What about `sum(-12)` ?

Comment: @Stef That's how the sum is defined. It starts from `k=1` and goes up to `n`. If `n < k` the sum is 0.

Comment: You should also warn against using `sum` as the name for a function; `sum` is already the name of a builtin in python and shadowing builtins is dangerous.

Comment: @Stef https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Special_cases

Comment: I assume you meant *n < 1* and not *n < k*? But your code does not check for *n < 1*. It checks for *n == 0*.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would easily reach the maximum recursion limit.

when you call again the function using 1/n and 1/n+1 you would use the same n and increase it, so you would never reach the end condition.
the next couple of sum would never have an n value equal to 0 or 1.

Also you should not call again the function with 1/n otherwise you would endup looping forever in the function recall

you should use something like:

```
>>> def my_sum(n):
...     if n < 1:
...             return 0
...     return 1/n + my_sum(n-1)
... 
>>> print(my_sum(3))
1.8333333333333333
>>> 11/6
1.8333333333333333
>>>
```

edit:
Like mentioned in another answer you should avoid using sum as a name of a function because it's a name already use by python

Comment: You could replace `if n == 0:  return 0 elif n == 1: return 1` with simply `if n < 1: return 0`. Also please don't encourage using `sum` as the name for a custom function; this is already the name of a builtin function in python.